# Gimp does not start

Tags: gimp

My gimp does not start, I get the following error:

```
gimp
/usr/share/themes/Yuyo-Dark/gtk-2.0/Apps/libreoffice.rc:40: Unable to locate image file in pixmap_path: "Entry/entry-border-bg-solid.png"
/usr/share/themes/Yuyo-Dark/gtk-2.0/Apps/libreoffice.rc:43: Background image options specified without filename
/usr/share/themes/Yuyo-Dark/gtk-2.0/Apps/libreoffice.rc:49: Unable to locate image file in pixmap_path: "Entry/entry-border-active-bg-solid.png"
/usr/share/themes/Yuyo-Dark/gtk-2.0/Apps/libreoffice.rc:52: Background image options specified without filename
```

Comment: this affects your theme as you can see not gimp try to check it with default Ambiance theme and then type `gimp` in terminal to see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Try simply reinstalling GIMP. Run in a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge gimp
sudo apt-get remove gimp
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install gimp
gimp
```

Answer (score 2):

I've just had the same problem

remove the yuyo-gtk-theme package and reinstall it (probably together with ubuntu-mate-core as its being removed as well)

My problem wasn't exactly gimp, but the error was the same and gimp and my problematic program are now running as they should